# Post body not working with wp_remote_post()

Tags: api, wp-api, wp-remote-post

I'm trying to post with with the following code

```
    $userTokenApi = 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/usertoken/issue';

    $args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'SiteId' => '6387',
            'Api-Key' => '7bba39594b4d460293abdfd64c8eea48'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'Username' => 'myusername',
            'Password' => 'mypassword'
        )
    );

    $request = wp_remote_post($userTokenApi, $args);
    $responseCode = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false; // Bail Early
    }

    $pretty = json_decode( $body ); ?>
```

But the response I'm getting back from the API is

```
Error:
Code: "MissingRequiredFields"
Message: "The following parameters are required: Username, Password"
```

The standard HTTP request for the same action (with PHP) is seen here https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6#user-tokens and using postman I'm able to post and receive my response fine with PHP - HTTP Request2, PHP - cURL, and any other type of code.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here or what I don't understand in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/)

Any help would be amazing.  Live issue can be seen [here](http://naada.staging.wpengine.com/vod/) - error's in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and `wp_remote_post()` doesn't intelligently JSON-encode the request data (the `body` array), so you should manually do it. So for example:

```php
'body' => json_encode( array(
    'Username' => 'myusername',
    'Password' => 'mypassword'
) )
```

Comment: That was it!   Thank you for showing me the problem, so I can see it next time. :-D